# php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll bindValue crash

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, windows-server-2008, php-extension

I'm developing a PHP application that connects to MSSQL on windows environment, I have

1. Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - 64-bit operating system
2. WAMP 2.5 - 64-bit (Apache 2.4.9 / PHP 5.5.12)
3. I've installed the official Microsoft SQL PDO Drivers (php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll, php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll)
4. I've connected to the database successfully, and executed different queries

I've two problems

1. Every time the WAMP starts I found these errors in the error log

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - %1 is not a
>   valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - %1 is not a
>   valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0

2. When I try to use PDO method ([bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)) ... the page crashes .. don't throw specific error or warning or anything .. just this message in the browser "This site can’t be reached" ... and the same two errors appear in the PHP error_log

Answer (score 0):

The `PDO_SQLSRV` is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface to enable access from PHP to MS SQL Server (starting with SQL Server 2005).

The extension is enabled by adding appropriate DLL file to your PHP extension directory and the corresponding entry to the `php.ini` file, which appears to have been done in your installation. The `PDO_SQLSRV` file download comes as 8 driver files, 4 of which are for PDO support. 
The `ts/nts` abbreviation in file names below means `Thread-safe` /`Non-thread-safe` respectively.

1. If you are running non-thread-safe PHP (PHP 5.3), use the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll` file. (You should use a `nts` version if you are using IIS as your web server).
2. If you are running `ts` PHP, use the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll` file.
3. Similarly for PHP 5.4, use the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll` or `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` depending on whether your PHP installation is non-thread-safe or thread-safe.

The most recent version of the driver is available for download [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx). If you need support for PHP 5.2 and/or PHP compiled with VC6, use the 2.0 [release](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV20.EXE) of the driver.